# how to prevent auto-resizing a dijit.dialog containing a dijit form?

Tags: dojo, dialog

I have a `dijit.dialog` containing a templated `form`. When the dialog is visible and I resize the window, the form height decreases(even if I increase/decrease window size). What is causing this weird behavior and how to prevent it?
Thanks.

code:
@LoginForm.html--

```
<form  data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"
    data-dojo-attach-event="onreset:_onReset, onsubmit:_onSubmit">
    ..
    ..
</form>
```

@LoginForm.js--

```
dojo.declare("LoginForm", [dijit.form.Form], {

  widgetsInTemplate: true,
  templateString: dojo.cache('template/LoginForm.html'),

  name: 'Login',
  'class': 'loginForm',
  'context': {'message':'hello'},

  action: '/authenticate',
  method: 'POST',
  onSubmit: function(event) {
  // something here
  },
  postCreate: function(){
  //
  },
  startup: function(){
   this.inherited(arguments);
  }
});
```

@index.html(this is shown on browser which calls LoginForm.js, creates an instance of the widget, places it at `dojo.body()` and shows it )--

Comment: Does the dialog resize (and get smaller) everytime you resize the browser window, or only the first time?

Comment: it does get smaller on every window resize (event?). once it collapses  into its minimum size(the size of the title bar) It cant resize anymore.

Comment: In fact it's the conrainerNode for the form which gets resized (smaller). Thus the dialog having only one child resizes according to the child ie. the containerNode.

Comment: Can't you fix the size of your dialog with something like new dijit.Dialog({
      title: "My Dialog",
      content: "test content",
      style: "width: 300px, height: 300px"
  });

Comment: Yes I can do that but I don't think that's a solution, it's just a workaround. Anyways if it's a bug then I might have to do that, but still I'm curious about its origin. I didn't find anyone(on the Internet) having this problem although the case here is not so rare(form inside a dialog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research of few hours on this, and found a trace.

When the window is resized, it tries to call `Form.resize()` expecting that the form will call `resize` on its children. But since Form isn't a layout widget nothing happens. I overrode the `resize()` of the form( to do nothing!) the bug seems to be vanished.

I am still not sure if I have the complete solution( after all overriding is not a way of fixing something). If anyone has a better explanation/solution please enlighten me.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually, `dijit.form.Form` does have a `resize()` method, it inherits from `dijit.layout._ContentPaneResizeMixin`.  You might want to play around the `doLayout` property of `dijit.Dialog` and see if that affects the resizing issue.